# Left invariant k-form

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

I am facing a question, have just started to read a chapter from Smoth Manifolds by Lee and having trouble to do this excercise

Let w be a left invariant k-form on a Lie group G. Show
that dw is a left invariant (k+1)-form.

I have re-read the definations but I can't proceed anywhere,
I am new members in this site,I don't know many rules, but if I violate any, please forgive me.

Gracias señor!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is an invariant form and $g\in G$, denote $L_g$ the left translation,
$L_g^*\alpha=\alpha$ implies that $d(L_g^*\alpha)=L_g^*d\alpha=d\alpha$ since the exterior derivative commutes with pullbacks.

[Proving that the pullback map commutes with the exterior derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302562/proving-that-the-pullback-map-commutes-with-the-exterior-derivative)

Comment: Gracias Señor, I have solved it. Thank you very much again..